# Extract changesets between last two tags in Mercurial

Tags: python, parsing, child-process

I have written the following script that I'd like to have reviewed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

os.system('hg tags > tags.txt')
file = 'tags.txt'
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)
fp = open(path)
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    if i == 1:
        latestTagLine = line      
    elif i == 2:
        previousTagLine = line    
    elif i > 4:
        break
fp.close()
revLatestTag = latestTagLine.split(':')
l = revLatestTag[0].split(' ')
revPreviousTag = previousTagLine.split(':')
p = revPreviousTag[0].split(' ')
command = 'hg log -r {}:{} > diff.txt'.format(l[-1],p[-1])
os.system(command)
```

Output of *hg tags* command:

> ```
> tip                         523:e317b6828206
> TOOL_1.4                    522:5bb1197f2e36
> TOOL_1.3                    515:7362c0effe40
> TOOL_1.1                    406:33379f244971
> ```

Comment: I don't normally edit the code in the question to fix the whitespace. However, since you double-spaced the entire post, including the `hg tags` output (which the code expects to be single-spaced), I assume that the double-spacing is unintentional, and have fixed it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify that you wanted to leave a `tags.txt` file as an intentional side-effect of your script.  I'm going to assume that it's an unwanted temporary file.  In that case, you can read the output of `hg` directly through a pipe.  Furthermore, the file object can be [used as an iterator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) to fetch just two lines, with no for-loop.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Read the first two lines of `hg tags`
with Popen(['hg', 'tags'], stdout=PIPE).stdout as hg_log:
    latestTagLine = hg_log.next()
    previousTagLine = hg_log.next()
```

The code to interpret each line is repeated, and therefore deserves to be put into a reusable function.  Instead of splitting, use a capturing regular expression.

```
import re

def parse_tag_line(line):
    match = re.match(r'^(.*) *(\d+):(.*)', line)
    return dict([
        ('tag', match.group(1)),
        ('rev', match.group(2)),
        ('hash', match.group(3)),
    ])
```

Finish up by generating the output:

```
log_range = '%s:%s' % (latestTag['hash'], previousTag['hash'])
with open('diff.txt', 'w') as diff:
    Popen(['hg', 'log', '-r', log_range], stdout=diff)
```

---

> Personally, I would prefer to just dump the output to `sys.stdout`, and use the shell to redirect the script's output to a file (`script > diff.txt`) instead of hard-coding `diff.txt` in the script itself.  Then, the epilogue would become
>
> ```
> log_range = '%s:%s' % (latestTag['hash'], previousTag['hash'])
> Popen(['hg', 'log', '-r', log_range])
> ```

---

Putting it all together:

```
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def parse_tag_line(line):
    match = re.match(r'^(.*) *(\d+):(.*)', line)
    return dict([
        ('tag', match.group(1)),
        ('rev', match.group(2)),
        ('hash', match.group(3)),
    ])

# Read the first two lines of `hg tags`
with Popen(['hg', 'tags'], stdout=PIPE).stdout as hg_log:
    latestTag = parse_tag_line(hg_log.next())
    previousTag = parse_tag_line(hg_log.next())

log_range = '%s:%s' % (latestTag['hash'], previousTag['hash'])

# Write `hg log -r ...:...` to diff.txt
with open('diff.txt', 'w') as diff:
    Popen(['hg', 'log', '-r', log_range], stdout=diff)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Your code does not run. I'll assume `latestTagLine` should be indented once more and the ` is to be removed at the end of the line.
2. <del>You have way too much blank lines, it doesn't help anyone.</del> *Formatting subsequently cleaned up.*
3. You could use [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html) to make your code clearer
4. You don't need to iterate on fp is all you need is the second and the third line. The easiest solution would be to use `readlines`. There could be a performance drawback if the file was big at the beginning. This can easily be fixed by redirecting the output of `hg tags` in `head -n 4` at the beginning.

At the end, my code would be :

```
import os
os.system('hg tags > tags.txt')
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tags.txt')) as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    l = lines[1].split(':')[0].split(' ')[-1]
    p = lines[2].split(':')[0].split(' ')[-1]
command = 'hg log -r {}:{} > diff.txt'.format(l,p)
os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is superfluous to write

```
file = 'tags.txt'
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file)
fp = open(path)
```

since the `tags.txt` is automatically interpreted as a path relative to the current directory.

This is sufficient:

```
fp = open('tags.txt')
```